# vb6 Windows Service Issue

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 Windows  Service which i am trying to migrate it to 2008 from 2003 server and getting the below error,

"Windows could not start the  Service-03 service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Is that i have to install anything to run vb6 windows service applications on windows server 2008 ?

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for this, your service should hace a log where you can investigate further. 
Take a look at windows events, there could be more information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the executable directly by doubleclicking the EXE (bypassing the Windows service handling) you will get popups if there's some ressources missing.